# LEFT LOOP JOIN in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am getting a warning message when I run even a simple select query against a view saying

> The Join Order has been enforced because a local join hint is used.

The view has been modified recently and the change was using Left loop join for one of the joins from before.

Can anyone please tell me how to suppress this warning message?

Please provide me sample examples.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` to the end of the query.

```
SELECT *
    FROM TableA a
        LEFT LOOP JOIN TableB b
            ON a.Col1 = b.Col1
    OPTION (FORCE ORDER);
```

Comment: @ Joe...Thanks a lot for the quick turn around thats helps a lot thank You.